# How to trigger a click from within an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, triggers, click, directive

I wonder how I can trigger a click from within an angularjs/1.6.4 directive.

Basically this code works partially:

```
app.directive('abc', function() {
  return {
    :
    :
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          :
       setTimeout(function(){element[0].click();}, 400);
          :
    }
  }
});
```

However the problem is if the page takes longer than 400ms to load. In this case it does not work. Therefore I would prefer a solution that didn't depend on a specified timeout period but a method that worked no matter how long the page took to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout` without a `milliseconds` parameter, so it execute the function in the next tick. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/3745365).

```
app.directive('abc', function() {
  return {
    :
    :
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          :
       setTimeout(function(){element[0].click();});
          :
    }
  }
});
```